# System of Divided Powers on $\mathrm{Tor}^R(k,k)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I was reading Gulliksen and Levin's (GL) text *Homology of Local Rings*, and I have a question about something in Chapter 2. Given a local commutative ring $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$, they say that $\mathrm{Tor}^R(k,k)$ is a divided power algebra and the divided power structure is inherited from the divided power structure of a DG $R$-algebra resolution that has a system of divided powers (which they refer to as an $(R)$-algebra). So I was wondering the following:

1. Is this independent of choice of $(R)$-algebra resolution of $k$, and if so, where can I find a proof of this (I might have missed it in GL, but I can't locate this there).
2. I am also curious of where I can find a proof that every $(R)$-algebra resolution of $k$ induces a divided power algebra structure on $\mathrm{Tor}^R(k,k)$. I know that an acyclic closure does, but I was wondering why this holds more generally (again, if you could point me to a source or where in GL this is I would greatly appreciate it!).

If I am mistaken about something please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the terminology since I have not this reference at hand now, but I think I have understood the question. If $R$ is torsion-free then the divided power structure in a $R$-resolution is determined by the product, so a map between two resolutions will preserve the PD structure, and so taking Tor the identity map will preserve the PD structure, i.e., both PD structures will agree. This answers (1) and also you can derive from it a proof of (2). If $R$ is not torsion-free, take a surjective map $S \to R$ with $S$ torsion-free.

Comment: I guess I'm not quite sure what you mean that the system of divided powers is determined by the product. Could you elaborate on this or recommend a reference to this? Thanks!

Comment: $n!X^{(n)}=X^n$ where $X^{(n)}$ denotes $n$-th divided power, so if there is no torsion, $X^n$ determines $X^{(n)}$.